# In the real quaternion ring, for any $t$ where $t^2=-1$, there exists a $s$ such that $sts^{-1} = i$

Tags: abstract-algebra, quaternions, splitting-field

While studying the notions of Extension fields and Splitting fields, I came across to handle the following question:

**Consider the real quaternion ring $R$. Then for any $t \in R$ satisfying $t^2=-1$, prove that we can find a $s \in R$ such that $sts^{-1} = i$.**

First I have found that, every $t \in R$ being a square of $-1$ in $R$ is pure imaginary unit quaternion; that is
\begin{gather*}
t = a_1 i + a_2 j + a_3 k, \quad a_1^2 + a_2^2 + a_3^2 =1
\end{gather*}
for any real $a_1, a_2, a_3 \in \mathbb{R}$. And I also have found that we can isomorphically identify the real quaternions with the elements in $M_2(\mathbb{C})$ as
\begin{gather*}
a_0 + a_1 i + a_2 j + a_3 k \iff \begin{pmatrix} a_0+a_1i & a_2+a_3i \\ -a_2+a_3i & a_0-a_1i\end{pmatrix}.
\end{gather*}
Then I merely tried to make a matrix calculation if what kind of element would $s^{-1}is$ be. By identifying $i \in R$ with $\begin{pmatrix} i &0 \\ 0 & -i\end{pmatrix}$,  I came to conclude that $t$ satisfying $t=s^{-1}is$ must be $-i$. But, this is definitely not the question wanted. So I have some doubts; whether I am misunderstanding the question or there is another brilliant way to tackle the problem.

If it was to find **some** $t$ (such that $t^2=-1$) and $s \in R$ satisfying $sts^{-1} =i$, the problem would be too easy. I like to get some advice. Please help!

Comment: Did you know that if $s=\exp(\theta v)$ (where $v$ is pure imaginary unit quaternion) then $sts^{-1}$ is $t$ rotated by $2\theta$ around $v$?

Comment: Note that your title and your body ask two different questions! Your title asks for a single $s$ that works for *every* $t$ with $t^2=-1$; same $s$ for every $t$. Your post asks to show that for each $t$ with $t^2=-1$ there is an $s$ (which may depend on $t$ and be different for different $t$s) that works.

Comment: @Arturo Magidin Oh yes, I was sloppy on making the title. I shall edit it. Thanks!

Comment: @runway44 Uhm, I have not even thought of that. This is a problem from a undergraduate algebra text, with no much explanation about the geometric feature of real quaternions

Comment: You dind’t fix it; now you are asking for a single $s$ that works for either all $t$, as before, or for a particular $t$ only. It’s not the question you are asking in the post.

Comment: @Arturo Magidin I confused with the usage of word  "a". Changed the title again.

Answer (score 1):

It was a good start that you figured out that we must have
$$
t=a_1i+a_2j+a_3k
$$
for some triple $(a_1,a_2,a_3)\in\Bbb{R}^3$ such that $a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2=1$. To find a suitable $s$ we do the following.

**Case 1.** If $a_2=a_3=0$ the task is easy. We must have $t=\pm i$. If $t=i$ we can use $s=1$. If $t=-i$ we can use $s=j$ as $jij^{-1}=-i$.

**Case 2.** Either $a_2\neq0$ or $a_3\neq0$. In this case the vectors $i$ and $t$ are linearly independent. Therefore their cross product $i\times t$ is a non-zero vector.
Furthermore, the angle $\theta$ between $i$ and $t$ is in the interval $\theta\in(0,\pi)$. Here we can use the following trick (well known to people using quaternions when implementing 3D-rotations in e.g. computer graphics, see also runway44's comment).
Let $u$ be the vector $i\times t$ scaled to have unit length. Then
$$
s=\cos(\theta/2)-u \sin(\theta/2)
$$
will work. This is because the linear transformation $v\mapsto svs^{-1}$ is the rotation about the axis $u$ by angle $\theta$. Remark: More often the sources uses
$$
s^{-1}=\cos(\theta/2)+u\sin(\theta/2),
$$
but then the rotation would map $i$ to $t$ rather than the other way arouns as we want here.

**Example.** Let $t=j$. We know that $i\times j=k$, so $u=k$. We know also that the angle between $i$ and $j$ is $\theta=\pi/2$. The recipe gives
$$
s=\cos\frac{\pi}4-k\sin\frac{\pi}4=\frac{1-k}{\sqrt2}.
$$
This has unit norm, so we know that
$$
s^{-1}=\overline{s}=\frac{1+k}{\sqrt2}.
$$
We can verify that
$$
\begin{aligned}
sjs^{-1}&=\frac1{\sqrt2}(1-k)j\frac1{\sqrt2}(1+k)\\
&=\frac12(j-kj)(1+k)\\
&=\frac12(j+i)(1+k)\\
&=\frac12(j+jk+i+ik)\\
&=\frac12(j+i+i-j)\\
&=i
\end{aligned}
$$
as prescribed.